# Can I Add Placeholder Text Into A Groovy Text Field (g:textField)?

Tags: grails, input, placeholder, gsp, grails-3.2

In my Grails3 Project on my .gsp I have a Relationship Label followed by an Relationship Groovy textField using the code below:

```html
    <div class="row top-margin">

    <!-- RELATIONSHIP LABEL -->
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-bottom: 0.1cm">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-6" style="font-weight: normal;" for="customerRelationship">
                        Relationship to Customer (spouse, sibling, stranger, etc.):
            </label>
        </div>

    <!-- RELATIONSHIP INPUT -->
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-bottom: 0.1cm">
            <g:textField class="form-control" name="customerRelationship" value="${customerRelationship}"
                                 style="width: 200px;"/>
        </div>
</div>
```

I would like to put a "placeholder" text into the textField to display while the field is empty. You can do this on an < input> tag by defining the placeholder value for the input.

My end goal is to make the lable only read "Relationship to Customer:" and to move the "spouse, sibling, stranger, etc." into the textField like a placeholder.

How would I go about this using a < g:textField> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Just simply add the `placeholder` attribute to the tag and it should include it in the rendered HTML (seem to recall this is the default behavior for all the `g` taglibs).

So:

```
<g:textField placeholder="Your text here" ... />
```